# How to await setState on next js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When I setOutput in handleSubmit function I expected my output tabs to show up after loading screen is gone but it takes some time (~20 second) before they show up. Btw I'm not talking about the content of the tabs, they just don't show up on navigation bar. I assume that since size of the output is almost 30 MB, it takes some time till setOutput is done but I don't see any reason why the tablinks are not show up immediately when I set showOutputTab to true. How can I keep loading page till all the tabs are rendered ?

```
//imported required modules here

const Preloader = dynamic(() => import('components/elements/Preloader'));
const ErrorModal = dynamic(() => import('components/modals/error_modal'));
const SaveProjectModal = dynamic(
    () => import('components/modals/save_project_modal'),
);
const FailedAnalysisModal = dynamic(
    () => import('components/modals/failed_analysis_modal'),
);
const ResponseSpectraTab = dynamic(() => import('./tabs/ResponseSpectraTab'));
const TimeSeriesTab = dynamic(() => import('./tabs/TimeSeriesTab'));
const ProfileTab = dynamic(() => import('./tabs/ProfileTab'));
const ReportTab = dynamic(() => import('./tabs/ReportTab'));

function GRAPage() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [isLoggedin, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
    const handleLoggedIn = (isLoggedIn: boolean) => {
        if (isLoggedIn) {
            setIsLoggedIn(true);
            return;
        }
        router.replace('/authentication/login');
    };
    const appName = 'groundResponseAnalysis';
    const session = useSession();
    const user = session?.user;
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [data, setData] = useState(initialState as types.InputData);
    const [output, setOutput] = useState({ reportUrl: '' } as OutputData);
    const [savedProjects, setSavedProjects] = useState([]);
    const [usageId, setUsageId] = useState('' as string);
    const [selectedProject, setSelectedProject] = useState('');
    const [showOutputTab, setShowOutputTab] = useState(false);
    const [showFailedAnalysisModal, setShowFailedAnalysisModal] =
        useState(false);
    const [reportTemplates, setReportTemplates] = useState([
        'Varsayılan Şablon',
    ]);
    const [selectedTemplate, setSelectedTemplate] =
        useState('Varsayılan Şablon');

    const [errorModalContent, setErrorModalContent] = useState({
        title: '',
        content: '',
        show: false,
    });
    const [projectModalContent, setProjectModalContent] = useState({
        projectName: '',
        errorMessage: '',
        show: false,
    });

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            await pf.listSavedProjects(
                user,
                appName,
                setSavedProjects,
                setSelectedProject,
            );
            await listReportTemplates(user, appName, setReportTemplates);
            setLoading(false);
        };
        setUsageId(create_UUID());
        fetchData();
    }, [session]);

    async function handleSubmit() {
        const { errorDiv, errorMessage, isValid } = validation(data);

        if (!isValid) {
            setErrorModalContent({
                title: errorDiv,
                content: errorMessage,
                show: true,
            });
            return;
        }
        setLoading(true);
        try {
            const output_ = await graHandler(
                data,
                selectedTemplate,
                user?.id as string,
            );
            setOutput(output_);
            setShowOutputTab(true);
            setLoading(false);
        } catch (error) {
            setLoading(false);
            setShowFailedAnalysisModal(true);
            const err = error as Error;
            sendError(err, data, user?.id as string, appName, usageId);
        }
    }

    const showProjectModal = () => {
        setProjectModalContent({ ...projectModalContent, show: true });
    };

    const handleSaveProject = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        const projectName = projectModalContent.projectName;
        const errorMessage = pf.validateProjectName(projectName);
        if (errorMessage) {
            setProjectModalContent({
                ...projectModalContent,
                errorMessage: errorMessage,
            });
            setLoading(false);
            return;
        }
        if (!user) return;

        const response = await pf.saveProject(
            data,
            user.id,
            appName,
            projectModalContent.projectName,
            'projects',
        );
        if (response.status === 200) {
            await pf.listSavedProjects(
                user,
                appName,
                setSavedProjects,
                setSelectedProject,
            );
            setLoading(false);
            alert('Proje başarıyla kaydedildi');
        } else {
            setLoading(false);
            alert('Proje kaydedilirken bir hata oluştu');
        }
        setProjectModalContent({ ...projectModalContent, show: false });
    };

    const handleLoadProject = async () => {
        if (!user) return;
        setLoading(true);
        const response = await pf.loadProject(
            user.id,
            appName,
            selectedProject,
        );
        const savedData = response.message;
        setData(savedData.inputData);
        setLoading(false);
        alert('Proje başarıyla yüklendi');
    };

    const handleInputChange = (e: any, dataType: string) => {
        const { id, name, value, checked } = e.target;
        if (dataType === 'boolean') {
            setData({ ...data, [id]: checked });
        } else if (dataType === 'int') {
            setData({ ...data, [name]: parseInt(value) || value });
        } else if (dataType === 'float') {
            setData({ ...data, [name]: parseFloat(value) || value });
        } else {
            setData({ ...data, [name]: value });
        }
    };

    const contextData: types.ContextData = useMemo(() => {
        return {
            data,
            setData,
            output,
            setOutput,
            showFailedAnalysisModal,
            setShowFailedAnalysisModal,
            errorModalContent,
            setErrorModalContent,
            handleInputChange,
        };
    }, [
        data,
        setData,
        output,
        setOutput,
        showFailedAnalysisModal,
        setShowFailedAnalysisModal,
        errorModalContent,
        setErrorModalContent,
        handleInputChange,
    ]);
    return (
        <DataContext.Provider value={contextData}>
            <CheckUserLoggedIn onLoggedIn={handleLoggedIn} />
            <div className="m-5">
                {!loading && isLoggedin ? (
                    <tab.TabWrapper defaultIndex={showOutputTab ? 1 : 0}>
                        <tab.TabBar>
                            <tab.TabLink title="Veri Girişi" />
                            <tab.TabLink
                                title="Zaman Serileri"
                                hide={!showOutputTab}
                            />
                            <tab.TabLink
                                title="Tepki Spektrumları"
                                hide={!showOutputTab}
                            />
                            <tab.TabLink
                                title="Zemin Profili Grafikleri"
                                hide={!showOutputTab}
                            />
                            <tab.TabLink
                                title="Rapor"
                                hide={output.reportUrl === ''}
                            />
                        </tab.TabBar>
                        <tab.TabContentWrapper>
                            <tab.TabContent id="input-tab">
                                <SavedProjectsList
                                    projects={savedProjects}
                                    selectedProject={selectedProject}
                                    setSelectedProject={setSelectedProject}
                                    onLoadProject={handleLoadProject}
                                />
                                <InputTab
                                    templates={reportTemplates}
                                    selectedTemplate={selectedTemplate}
                                    setSelectedTemplate={setSelectedTemplate}
                                />
                                <div className="ml-5 mt-5 space-x-3">
                                    <button.SubmitButton onClick={handleSubmit}>
                                        Analiz Yap
                                    </button.SubmitButton>
                                    <button.BorderButton
                                        onClick={showProjectModal}
                                    >
                                        Projeyi Kaydet
                                    </button.BorderButton>
                                </div>
                            </tab.TabContent>
                            {showOutputTab && (
                                <>
                                    <tab.TabContent id="time-series-tab">
                                        <TimeSeriesTab />
                                    </tab.TabContent>
                                    <tab.TabContent id="response-spectra-tab">
                                        <ResponseSpectraTab />
                                    </tab.TabContent>

                                    <tab.TabContent id="profile-tab">
                                        <ProfileTab />
                                    </tab.TabContent>
                                    {data.giveReport && (
                                        <tab.TabContent id="report-tab">
                                            <ReportTab
                                                reportUrl={output.reportUrl}
                                            />
                                        </tab.TabContent>
                                    )}
                                </>
                            )}
                        </tab.TabContentWrapper>
                    </tab.TabWrapper>
                ) : (
                    <Preloader />
                )}
                {errorModalContent.show && (
                    <ErrorModal
                        modalContent={errorModalContent}
                        setModalContent={setErrorModalContent}
                    />
                )}
                {showFailedAnalysisModal && (
                    <FailedAnalysisModal
                        setModalContent={setShowFailedAnalysisModal}
                        showModal={showFailedAnalysisModal}
                    />
                )}
                {projectModalContent.show && (
                    <SaveProjectModal
                        modalContent={projectModalContent}
                        setModalContent={setProjectModalContent}
                        onSave={handleSaveProject}
                    />
                )}
            </div>
        </DataContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default GRAPage;
```

I expect to see output tabs on nav bar immediately after I set loading to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

The issue you're facing is due to the asynchronous nature of the `setState` function. When you call `setOutput` and `setShowOutputTab`, the state updates don't happen instantly. Instead, React batches these updates and performs them in a subsequent re-render. Thus, even if you call `setLoading(false)` immediately after updating the state, React might not have completed the state updates for `output` and `showOutputTab`.

To ensure that the loading state is set to false only after your output tabs have been processed, you can use the `useEffect` hook that listens for changes in the `output` state:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (output && Object.keys(output).length > 0) {
        setLoading(false);
    }
}, [output]);
```

By doing this, when the `output` state changes (i.e., after `setOutput` has been called in your `handleSubmit` function), this `useEffect` will execute, checking if the output has any content and then setting the loading state to false.

This should ensure that your output tabs show up on the navigation bar right when the loading is complete.